# Android : application crashes with BadTokenException Error (trying to show AlertDialog)

Tags: java, android, exception, android-alertdialog

I simply want to print an alert on the screen if there is no connection.

Here is what I did in my class that extends Activity.

```
if(isOnline()) { 
    // do stuff..
} else {
    Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setMessage("No connection.");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Then I tried to launch it with Debug, and got the following error :

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
 Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(Your_Current_Activity.this);
```

instead of

```
 Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

because you will need to pass Current Activity Context to show `AlertDialog` instead of Application Context

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line

```
Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

with

```
Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```

Since you may need an **Activity Context** instead of **Application Context**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yourActivityName.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`;

Answer (score 1):

try to use `classname.this` other than `getApplicationContext()` this some time cause issues

```
if(isOnline()) { 
    // do stuff..
} else {
    Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setMessage("No connection.");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```